# Simple Injector 4.1: Overriding Parameter Injection Behavior

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I'm new to using DI in C# and had a look at Windsor, Ninject, Autofac, Unity and Simple Injector. I originally discarded Simple Injector because I needed value-type injection (fx. connection strings) but found a blogpost describing this: https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=94. Unfortunately the blogpost is outdated since `IDependencyInjectionBehavior.BuildExpression` is deprecated in version 4.1 and `IDependencyInjectionBehavior.GetInstanceProducer` has been introduced instead.
I'm not sure how to do what the blogpost describes with the new InstanceProducer. `InstanceProducer` has a static method `FromExpression` but I'm not sure which type etc. should be used.

I currently do Pure DI and have the following settings:

```
// Settings
var conLocal = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["APIPortMan"].ConnectionString;
var con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PortMan"].ConnectionString;
var conAzure = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Azure"].ConnectionString;
var conSitecore = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Sitecore"].ConnectionString;
var azureStorageAccount = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("StorageConnection");
var reportUploadPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ReportUploadPath");
var PfsmlPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("PfsmlPath");
var reloadCounter = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("transactionServiceReloadCounter"));
var systemStartDate = DateTime.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("holdingServiceStartDate"));
var semaphoreCount = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("semaphoreCount"));
```

Then I have some repositories consuming these settings:

```
// Repositories
var _accountRepository = new AccountRepository(con, conAzure);
var _aggregatedPortfolioRelationshipRepository = new AggregatedPortfolioRelationshipRepository(conAzure);
var _aggregatedClientRelationshipRepository = new AggregatedClientRelationshipRepository(con, conAzure);
var _assetBondRepository = new AssetBondRepository(con, conAzure);
var _assetClassRepository = new AssetClassRepository(con, conAzure);
var _assetDerivativeRepository = new AssetDerivativeRepository(con, conAzure);
var _assetRepository = new AssetRepository(con, conAzure);
var _benchmarkRepository = new BenchmarkRepository(con, conAzure);
var _benchmarkWeightRepository = new BenchmarkWeightRepository(con, conAzure);
var _clientRepository = new ClientRepository(con, conAzure);
var _defaultPriceRepository = new DefaultPriceRepository(con, conAzure);
var _emailRepository = new UpdateEmailOutput(conAzure);
var _exchangeRateRepository = new ExchangeRateRepository(con, conAzure);
var _failedHoldingRepository = new FailedHoldingRepository(conLocal);
var _GICSRepository = new GICSRepository(con, conAzure);
var _holdingRepository = new HoldingRepository(conAzure);
var _limitLineRepository = new LimitLineRepository(con, conAzure);
var _PFSMLRepository = new PFSMLRepository(PfsmlPath);
var _portfolioRepository = new PortfolioRepository(con, conAzure);
var _sitecoreReportRepository = new SitecoreReportRepository(conSitecore, reportUploadPath);
var _systemInfoRepository = new SystemInfoRepository(conAzure);
var _transactionRepository = new TransactionRepository(con, conAzure);
```

And later some services consuming the repositories and a few of the settings.

Since most of the repositories share a common interface `IRepository<T>` (besides an individual interface like `IAssetRepository` that extends IRepository with the type `Asset`) I would like to be able to use batch creation /auto-wiring. Also I would like to avoid changing the DI setup every time a change is made to my main code (ie. new constructor parameter, new repository interface/class etc.). Also I would like to avoid using lambda's, "new" and `getInstance` in the registration process because this will require changes to the DI setup whenever I change a constructor.

I have already adopted the convention mentioned in the blogpost (using `AzureConnectionString`, `PortManConnectionString` etc.) in the constructors. All I need to do now is make sure Simple Injector handles value type parameters according to the conventions :)

Comment: Duplicate: https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/526

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted the same question on Github (as Steven noted).
https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/blob/v4.0.x/src/SimpleInjector.CodeSamples/ParameterConventionExtensions.cs contains an updated version of the convention-based approach although Steven/dotnetjunkie convinced me to take a different approach (using settings-objects).